# Formatting Emailed dataset output

Tags: c#, sql, formatting, dataset

I have a program that runs by windows scheduler... Each time it runs, it runs a query on our database, grabs the information and then emails it.  It all works as advertised, however I can't seem to find out how to format the date and the dollar amount.  My C# code is:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Linq

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            Me.Paid_Out_TbTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.Paid_Out_Tb)
            Dim payouts = _
            <html>
                <body>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr><th>Store #</th><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th><th>User</th><th>Comment</th></tr>
                        <%= From paidOut In Me.DataSet.Paid_Out_Tb.AsEnumerable _
                            Select <tr><td><%= paidOut.Store_Id %></td>
                                       <td><%= paidOut.Paid_Out_Datetime %></td>
                                       <td><%= paidOut.Paid_Out_Amount %></td>
                                       <td><%= paidOut.Update_UserName %></td>
                                       <td><%= paidOut.Paid_Out_Comment %></td></tr> %>
                    </table>
                </body>

            </html>


            SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
            Net.NetworkCredential("****", "****")
            SmtpServer.Port = 25
            SmtpServer.Host = "10.0.*.*"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("***@***.com")
            mail.To.Add("***@***.com")
            'mail.CC.Add("***@**.com")
            mail.Subject = "Paid Out Report for 1929"
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            mail.Body = payouts.ToString()
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            'MsgBox("mail send")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try






        Me.Close()

    End Sub
```

My Query is:

```
SELECT        Store_Id, Paid_Out_Amount, Paid_Out_Comment, Paid_Out_Datetime, Update_UserName, Till_Number
FROM            Paid_Out_Tb
WHERE        (Store_Id = 1929) AND (Paid_Out_Datetime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) AND (Paid_Out_Datetime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, 
                         GETDATE()), 0)) AND (Paid_Out_Amount > 20) OR
                         (Store_Id = 1929) AND (Paid_Out_Datetime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) AND (Paid_Out_Datetime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, 
                         GETDATE()), 0)) AND (Paid_Out_Comment LIKE N'%' + 'Filter' + '%')
```

Lastly the output is:

```
Store # Date    Amount  User    Comment
1929    2012-07-22T12:18:23.33  29.0000 KAG PIZZA AND TIP FOR STORE
```

As you can see the date is in long form.. I'd just like 7/22/12 and the amount I would like $29.00...  How can I format the output correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `.ToString()`, passing in the correct format string, to get the formatting you want.  You might need to do some conversion beforehand, depending on what types, if any, are specified for your DataSet:

```
<td><%= Convert.ToDateTime(paidOut.Paid_Out_Datetime).ToString("M/d/yy") %></td>
<td><%= Convert.ToDecimal(paidOut.Paid_Out_Amount).ToString("0.00") %></td>
```

Comment: That worked, except it shortned the output of "Comment" to 1 word... just "Pizza"

Comment: @Shmewnix That must have been some other inadvertent change to your code, I suspect.  (Or it could have been a change in the data.)

Comment: I actually forgot I set it to grab "yesterday's" date... hence the reason the comments AND the amounts are different... It is pulling the 29th... Your convert and tostring worked perfectly.  Thanks!